# SQL SELECT variables within a distinct

Tags: sql

OKAY,  I Started with this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    IBX_Name AS "IBX",
    AST_UST_Level1 AS "Latest Main Tank 1 Level",
    AST_UST_Level2 AS "Latest Main Tank 2 Level",
    AST_UST_Level3 AS "Latest Main Tank 3 Level",
    RunData_Date AS "Last Date"
FROM RunData 

INNER JOIN Tanks ON Tanks.fk_GeneratorName_ID = RunData.fk_GeneratorName_ID
INNER JOIN IBXs ON IBXs.IBX_ID = Tanks.fk_IBX_ID
INNER JOIN GeneratorNames ON GeneratorNames.GeneratorName_ID = RunData.fk_GeneratorName_ID

WHERE ([RunData_Date] = (SELECT Max([RunData_Date]) FROM RunData AS T1 WHERE T1.fk_IBX_ID = IBX_ID AND (T1.AST_UST_Level1 > 0 OR T1.AST_UST_Level2 > 0 OR T1.AST_UST_Level3 > 0)))
```

And I received an ouput of this:

```
IBX        Latest Main Tank 1 Level Latest Main Tank 2 Level Latest Main Tank 3 Level Last Date
---------- ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ----------
DC2        16128                    16192                    NULL                     2018-11-08
DC4        25881                    26007                    NULL                     2020-03-18
DC5        24079                    23774                    NULL                     2020-03-13

(3 rows affected)
```

NOW, I tried to use this code:

```
DECLARE @MT1_ID AS INT, @MT2_ID AS INT, @MT3_ID AS INT

SELECT DISTINCT
    IBX_Name AS "IBX",
    @MT1_ID AS "Main Tank 1 ID",
    AST_UST_Level1 AS "Latest Main Tank 1 Level",
    @MT2_ID AS "Main Tank 2 ID",
    AST_UST_Level2 AS "Latest Main Tank 2 Level",
    @MT3_ID AS "Main Tank 3 ID",
    AST_UST_Level3 AS "Latest Main Tank 3 Level",
    RunData_Date AS "Last Date"
FROM RunData 

INNER JOIN Tanks ON Tanks.fk_GeneratorName_ID = RunData.fk_GeneratorName_ID
INNER JOIN IBXs ON IBXs.IBX_ID = Tanks.fk_IBX_ID
INNER JOIN GeneratorNames ON GeneratorNames.GeneratorName_ID = RunData.fk_GeneratorName_ID

WHERE ([RunData_Date] = (SELECT Max([RunData_Date]) FROM RunData AS T1 WHERE T1.fk_IBX_ID = IBX_ID AND (T1.AST_UST_Level1 > 0 OR T1.AST_UST_Level2 > 0 OR T1.AST_UST_Level3 > 0)))
AND @MT1_ID = (SELECT ([Tank_ID]) FROM Tanks WHERE Tanks.fk_IBX_ID = IBXs.IBX_ID AND Tanks.Main_Tank_Index = 1) 
AND @MT2_ID = (SELECT ([Tank_ID]) FROM Tanks WHERE Tanks.fk_IBX_ID = IBXs.IBX_ID AND Tanks.Main_Tank_Index = 2)
AND @MT3_ID = (SELECT ([Tank_ID]) FROM Tanks WHERE Tanks.fk_IBX_ID = IBXs.IBX_ID AND Tanks.Main_Tank_Index = 3)
```

Which gave me an output of:

```
IBX        Main Tank 1 ID Latest Main Tank 1 Level Main Tank 2 ID Latest Main Tank 2 Level Main Tank 3 ID Latest Main Tank 3 Level Last Date
---------- -------------- ------------------------ -------------- ------------------------ -------------- ------------------------ ----------

(0 rows affected)
```

**What am I missing so that I can insert the ID number prior to the level?**

Comment: Your variables are null and you are using a null comparison within your where clause therefore no records match your query.

Comment: On a side note: Why do you need `DISTINCT`? Why do you get duplicates that you must remove? And why do you join the table GeneratorNames?

Comment: What is your DBMS? SQL Server? SQLite? MS Access? ... Your SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: There is more information there that is tied to the entries....So if there can be seven entries from different machines but share the same three tanks.  And it is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables (all the words preceded by @) are declared but not initialised here

```
DECLARE @MT1_ID AS INT, @MT2_ID AS INT, @MT3_ID AS INT
```

so all your variables are NULL so when you use them later in your query you check if NULL is equal to something which is an invalid comparison so you will not get any results

I assume this is what you where trying to get

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    IBX_Name AS "IBX",
    (SELECT ([Tank_ID]) FROM Tanks WHERE Tanks.fk_IBX_ID = IBXs.IBX_ID AND Tanks.Main_Tank_Index = 1) AS "Main Tank 1 ID",
    AST_UST_Level1 AS "Latest Main Tank 1 Level",
    (SELECT ([Tank_ID]) FROM Tanks WHERE Tanks.fk_IBX_ID = IBXs.IBX_ID AND Tanks.Main_Tank_Index = 2) AS "Main Tank 2 ID",
    AST_UST_Level2 AS "Latest Main Tank 2 Level",
    (SELECT ([Tank_ID]) FROM Tanks WHERE Tanks.fk_IBX_ID = IBXs.IBX_ID AND Tanks.Main_Tank_Index = 3) AS "Main Tank 3 ID",
    AST_UST_Level3 AS "Latest Main Tank 3 Level",
    RunData_Date AS "Last Date"
FROM RunData 

INNER JOIN Tanks ON Tanks.fk_GeneratorName_ID = RunData.fk_GeneratorName_ID
INNER JOIN IBXs ON IBXs.IBX_ID = Tanks.fk_IBX_ID
INNER JOIN GeneratorNames ON GeneratorNames.GeneratorName_ID = RunData.fk_GeneratorName_ID

WHERE ([RunData_Date] = (SELECT Max([RunData_Date]) FROM RunData AS T1 WHERE T1.fk_IBX_ID = IBX_ID AND (T1.AST_UST_Level1 > 0 OR T1.AST_UST_Level2 > 0 OR T1.AST_UST_Level3 > 0)))
```

Comment: I had something similar to this initially, just not quite formatted correctly.  Thanks.